# Julia v1.0.2 Pkg.activate(".") in Docker container issue

Tags: docker, julia

I am building a Docker container for a Julia project and having an issue with Pkg.activate(".") to use the project's Project.toml file. Here is what I am doing:

```
FROM julia:1.0.2 AS base

ADD src/*.jl /microservice/src/

COPY Manifest.toml /microservice/Manifest.toml
COPY Project.toml /microservice/Project.toml

COPY src/startup.jl /root/.julia/config/startup.jl

WORKDIR /microservice

RUN julia -e 'cd("/microservice")'
RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.activate(".")'
RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()'
RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.status()'
RUN julia -e 'println(Base.active_project())'
```

When I build the container using the above Dockerfile code I can verify all source code and .toml files are in the container. The call to `Pkg.status()` results in: `Status ~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`

and `Base.active_project()` results in:
`/root/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`

What am I missing to have the call to `Pkg.activate(".")` use the Project.toml that I copy to `/microservice` ?

Comment: I've tried adding this to my startup.jl
empty!(DEPOT_PATH)
pushfirst!(DEPOT_PATH, "./")

but Julia adds additional paths to the created project environment such that `Pkg.status()` results in: `/microservice/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An activated environment is not persistent between julia sessions so you need to activate it in every session. Instead of starting each session with `using Pkg; Pkg.activate(".")` you have two better options:

1. Start julia with the `--project` flag (documented in a table on this page https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/#man-getting-started-1) i.e.

   ```
   RUN julia --project=/microservice -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()'
   RUN julia --project=/microservice -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.status()'
   RUN julia --project=/microservice -e 'println(Base.active_project())'
   ```
2. Set the `JULIA_PROJECT` environment flag (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_PROJECT-1)

   ```
   ENV JULIA_PROJECT=/microservice
   RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()'
   RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.status()'
   RUN julia -e 'println(Base.active_project())'
   ```

In this situation I would say that the second option is better, since I assume you will always use this package environment in your containers.

Comment: Option #2 is perfect..! Just tested and it works. Thank you @fredrikekre